# Spock - mock a Groovy closure method?

Tags: groovy, mocking, closures, spock, gdk

This is what I want to do:

```
def mockSubdirs = []
mockSubdirs << Mock( File ){
    getName() >> 'some subdir'
    lastModified() >> 2000
}
...

File mockParentDir = Mock( File ){
    getName() >> 'parent dir'
    eachDir() >> mockSubdirs.iterator() // ??? NB eachDir is a GDK method
    // I tried things along these lines:
    // listFiles() >> mockSubdirs
    // iterator() >> mockSubdirs.iterator()
}

cut.myDirectory = mockParentDir
```

The app code is like this:

```
def dirNames = []
myDirectory.eachDir{ 
    dirNames << it.name
}
```

All the above give `FileNotFoundException` on the `myDirectory.eachDir{` line...

***later***

Thanks to all 3 answerers for possible solutions to this.  Kriegaex's code example doesn't seem to work for me, and I'm not sure why.  However his suggestion of looking at the Groovy source code is great. So in NioGroovyMethods.java I find that `eachDir` calls `eachFile` which looks like this:

```
public static void eachFile(final Path self, final FileType fileType, @ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "java.nio.file.Path") final Closure closure) throws IOException {
        //throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException {
    checkDir(self);

    // TODO GroovyDoc doesn't parse this file as our java.g doesn't handle this JDK7 syntax
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(self)) {
        for (Path path : stream) {
            if (fileType == FileType.ANY ||
                    (fileType != FileType.FILES && Files.isDirectory(path)) ||
                    (fileType != FileType.DIRECTORIES && Files.isRegularFile(path))) {
                closure.call(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... so my first thought was to try to mock `Files.newDirectoryStream`.  `Files` is `final`, so you have to use a `GroovyMock`, and because the method is `static` you would appear to have to use something like this:

```
GroovyMock( Files, global: true )
Files.newDirectoryStream(_) >> Mock( DirectoryStream ){
    iterator() >> mockPaths.iterator()
}
```

... attempts along these lines don't seem to work... I wouldn't be at all surprised to hear from someone that the `Files` class in the Groovy language mechanism will not be affected by this attempt at a mock...

Then I thought that presumably `toPath` must be called on the `File` in question, so tried this:

```
File mockParentDir = Mock( File ){
    toPath() >> {
        println "toPath called"
        Mock( Path )
    }
}
```

... this line is not printed.  OK I'm a bit stumped: to get a `Path` from the `File` I give it the Groovy mechanism must be using something sneaky: maybe something like `getAbsolutePath()`... and then creating a `Path` from the resulting `String`? This would require more examination of the source code... but if this is the case, you wouldn't then be able coerce Groovy to use a mock `Path`!
or... maybe other mysterious Groovy things come into play here: metaclass, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are really trying to test.  Here is one example that might be helpful:

```
class DirectoryNameHelper {

    /*
     * This is silly, but facilitates answering a question about mocking eachDir
     */
    List<String> getUpperCaseDirectoryNames(File dir) {
        List<String> names = []
        dir.eachDir {File f ->
            names << f.name.toUpperCase()
        }
        names
    }
}
```

A test which mocks `eachDir`.  This really just tests that the method under test invokes eachDir and passes a closure which returns the upper case version of each directories name.

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import spock.lang.Specification

class EachDirMockSpec extends Specification {

    void 'test mocking eachDir'() {
        setup:
        def mockDirectory = new MockFor(File)
        mockDirectory.demand.eachDir { Closure c ->
                File mockFile = Mock() {
                    getName() >> 'fileOne'
                }
                c(mockFile)

                mockFile = Mock() {
                    getName() >> 'fileTwo'
                }
                c(mockFile)
        }

        when:
        def helper = new DirectoryNameHelper()
        def results
        mockDirectory.use {
            def f = new File('')
            results = helper.getUpperCaseDirectoryNames(f)
        }

        then:
        results == ['FILEONE', 'FILETWO']
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting... "demand"... "MockFor"... I'm going to have to go back to the Spock sources and do a bit more work to understand that! So what do you say to Szymon Stepniak's assertion "You can't mock eachDir that way, because this method ... is added dynamically"? As to what I'm trying to test: mock the method `File.lastModified`: the code doesn't show it but the directories must be sorted by their "lastModified" date (`long` in fact): consequently I can't use real (temporary) directories, so how do I get to iterate through a list of mock directories using `eachDir`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock `eachDir` that way, because this method does not belong to `File` class - it is added dynamically via [`ResourceGroovyMethods`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.13/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.html#eachDir-java.io.File-groovy.lang.Closure-) class. You will have to mock `listFiles()`, `exists()` and `isDirectory()` methods instead, e.g:

```
    File mockParentDir = Mock(File) {
        getName() >> 'parent_dir'
        listFiles() >> mockSubdirs
        exists() >> true
        isDirectory() >> true
    }
```

Mocking `exists()` and `isDirectory()` methods is mandatory, because mock returns default values if you don't specify one and for boolean the default value is `false` - in this case you will get `FileNotFoundException`. You will have to do the same thing for `mockSubdirs` if you expect it containing directories.

Here is an exemplary test that shows proper mocking:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class MockDirSpec extends Specification {

    def "test mocked directories"() {
        setup:
        def mockSubdirs = []
        mockSubdirs << Mock( File ){
            getName() >> 'some subdir'
            lastModified() >> 2000
            exists() >> true
            isDirectory() >> true
        }

        File mockParentDir = Mock(File) {
            getName() >> 'parent_dir'
            listFiles() >> mockSubdirs
            exists() >> true
            isDirectory() >> true

        }

        def cut = new ClassUnderTest()
        cut.myDirectory = mockParentDir

        when:
        def names = cut.names()

        then:
        names == ['some subdir']
    }

    static class ClassUnderTest {
        File myDirectory

        List<String> names() {
            def dirNames = []
            myDirectory.eachDir {
                dirNames << it.name
            }
            return dirNames
        }
    }
}
```

#### Mocking `eachDir` - the drawbacks

There is one major drawback when it comes to mocking `eachDir` function. It is pretty specific function by definition - it iterates over subdirectories only. It means that this part of app code from your example:

```
def dirNames = []
myDirectory.eachDir{ 
    dirNames << it.name
}
```

produces different result depending what `myDirectory` variable is referring to. For example:

- if `myDirectory` points to an empty directory, `dirNames` ends up being empty
- if `myDirectory` points to a directory containing several text files, `dirNames` ends up being empty
- if `myDirectory` points to a directory containing 2 subdirectories and 10 text files, `dirNames` ends up containing 2 elements, names of those subdirectories

If we mock `eachDir` so it always accepts same fixed input files, it doesn't matter if we call it on a variable representing empty directory or a directory containing 2 subdirectories and a few text files - the result in both cases is always the same.

What makes more sense to me in this case is to mock an input - a directory represented as `File`. Thanks to this you can simulate without creating a real file:

- an empty directory
- a directory with a single text file
- a directory with a single subdirectory
- a directory with tons of subdirectories and several text files
- etc.

And you don't have to mock the behavior of `eachDir` method, which is a huge benefit.

Another benefit is that you don't have to change your app code - you can still use `eachDir` function inside. When you mock input files instead of mocking `eachDir` method you just provide a test data that is stored in memory instead of a file system. Imagine creating a desired file structure and investigating what those `File` instances are represented by in the runtime with a debugger - you could replay what all public methods from `File` class return using values taken from the real file system. This could give you a nice "in-memory" simulation of what a specific directory looks like when stored in the file system. And you use it as an input data in your test to simulate what happens in the runtime. That's why I consider mocking `eachDir` harmful - it creates a scenario that does not appear in the runtime.

There is also a good blog post from Uncle Bob about mocking that can be summarized by a following conclusion:

> *"In short, however, I recommend that you mock sparingly. Find a way to test -- design a way to test -- your code so that it doesn't require a mock. Reserve mocking for architecturally significant boundaries; and then be ruthless about it. Those are the important boundaries of your system and they need to be managed, not just for tests, but for everything."*
>
> *Source: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html*

Comment: "You can't mock eachDir" - I don't think that is true.

Comment: There are a number of ways the `eachDir` method may be mocked.  `MockFor` is one.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I was referring to the way OP presented in the question. Defining `eachDir()` or `eachDir(_)` inside `Mock(File)` closure has no effect, I've tested it with the example shown in the answer. On the other hand - mocking this method wouldn't have any sense. It consumes a closure and does not return anything.

Comment: You could mock the method and have the mock implementation invoke the specified closure with whatever the test wants to provide to the closure.  I think the test would be testing the side effects of the closure being invoked with certain data, not what `eachDir` returns.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. I see mocking in this example as a way to provide an alternative to the file system and relying on a real `eachDir` method implementation, which is pretty specific (iterates over subdirectories of a given directory). I expect that for directory containing 2 subdirs and 5 text files this method executes given closure twice, for subdirs only. If I mock `eachDir`, I can change behavior of this method, just as you shown below when mocked `eachDir` accepts files that are not directories. I wouldn't call it a good example of a unit test.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Thanks for your explanation and suggestion how to look at this... but I can't agree with your assertion that it "wouldn't make sense" because "It consumes a closure and does not return anything". That is far too narrow a requirement for qualifying a mock as "valid", as Jeff implies, and indeed my example illustrates why.  Your objection that "you can change behaviour" doesn't make sense either: all mocking is contrived by nature and intimately dependent on the app code.  Finally, it is wrong to assume that this is a "unit test": functional tests are just as important.

Comment: Mike, with all due respect: Your last comment does not make much sense to me. Not "all mocking is contrived by nature". Testing as a whole only becomes contrived if the code under test is contrived. Having to look at the application source code at all for testing or mocking is a smell and a reason to refactor the application for better testability, e.g. via dependency injection. Furthermore, the fact that your test is a functional test and not a unit test does not invalidate Szymon's comment in the least.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, for a functional test nobody stops you from creating the directory structure you like to test as version-managed test resources. You can even manipulate the file dates to your liking when setting up the test fixture. Or just commit the files in the order you need them. If all else fails you can still just mock/stub the method returning the file date. Whatever, there are many options to achieve what you want, even without mocking away the whole file system. Then you have a real integration test.

Comment: @mikerodent My concern about mocking `eachDir` has a different source. Using a mock file in a test is useful in many cases - you can simulate a file size, you can mock its life cycle (created, updated, deleted) without concerning if a real file gets modified by a different process etc. However, mocking `eachDir` has one major drawback - if you mock it, it doesn't matter if you run it on empty directory, directory containing only text files or a directory containing 2 subdirs and some text files. In this case you loose ability to test those corner cases. I accept you have a different opinion.

Comment: @kriegaex & Szymon Stepniak - thanks for your expert comments. I've read them both very carefully.  Things I still don't understand: to "give up" on using a feature of Groovy (and use `listFiles` in the app code instead) seems a bit "defeatist"... & I don't see how I can "mock/stub the method returning the file date" unless (for example) I know what underlying Java methods (if any!) are being used by `eachDir` ... (`each` OTOH could potentially be easier to "gloss over" in that sense).  Surely the answer to Szymon's objection is to filter out non-directories in your mock substitute method...?

Comment: Think about it that way - create a directory with subdirs and files in it, use it temporarily in the test instead of mocks, investigate with a debugger what real files return for each `File` public method and replay the same values with mocks. It will allow you to have "fully" mocked file system directory representation, without touching a file system. You don't have to give up on any Groovy's features. It doesn't even matter what `eachDir` does under the hood. If you don't want to use a real file system you have to mimic it as close as possible with mock files, that's it.

Comment: And you don't have to change anything in your app code. The goal is to provide a test data that simulates what happens or may happen when your application is running. `eachDir` has some business logic behind this function. Your application does not mock it in the runtime, it relies on its implementation - that's why I suggest not mocking it in the test. Otherwise your test does not represent runtime use case anymore and you actually don't know what may happen when the application is running. Mocking input data allows you to model corner cases you want to test `eachDir` method with.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand! The Groovy source code, as you can see from my addendum, is using `Files.newDirectoryStream` to obtain its contents (files and directories). It is not therefore sufficient to "cover all bases" of `File`, i.e. the public methods.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to say thank you to both [Szymon Stepniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194470/szymon-stepniak) and [Jeff Scott Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533584/jeff-scott-brown) for their respective answers which were both really insightful and which I both upvoted for that reason. I suggest that the OP accepts the one of them he likes best, **not** this one, because here I am just unifying both approaches into one specification, using the same class under test and comparable variable naming in the feature methods. I also streamlined mock usage for the subdirectories to just use a single mock object which returns two different file names on subsequent calls via `getName() >>> ['subDir1', 'subDir2']`.

So now we can more easily compare both approaches which basically do this:

- Szymon's approach is to rely on on-board Spock means and is what should be used when testing Java classes. OTOH, we are dealing with `eachDir`, a Groovy-specific thing, here. The downside here is that in order to pull off this kind of mocking we really need to look at the source code for `eachDir` and one of its helper methods in order to find out what exactly needs to be stubbed so as to make it all work correctly. Still, it is straightforward and a valid solution IMO.
- Jeff's approach mixes Spock mocks with Groovy's own `MockFor`, making it a bit harder to read for me when I first encountered it. But this is just because I exclusively use Spock for testing Java applications, i.e. I am not a Groovy buff. What I do like about this approach is that it works without looking into `eachDir`'s source code.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import spock.lang.Specification

class MockDirTest extends Specification {

  def "Mock eachDir indirectly via method stubbing"() {
    setup:
    File subDir = Mock() {
      // Stub all methods (in-)directly used by 'eachDir'
      getName() >>> ['subDir1', 'subDir2']
      lastModified() >> 2000
      exists() >> true
      isDirectory() >> true
    }
    File parentDir = Mock() {
      // Stub all methods (in-)directly used by 'eachDir'
      getName() >> 'parentDir'
      listFiles() >> [subDir, subDir]
      exists() >> true
      isDirectory() >> true
    }
    def helper = new DirectoryNameHelper()

    when:
    def result = helper.getUpperCaseDirectoryNames(parentDir)

    then:
    result == ['SUBDIR1', 'SUBDIR2']
  }

  def "Mock eachDir directly via MockFor.demand"() {
    setup:
    File subDir = Mock() {
      getName() >>> ['subDir1', 'subDir2' ]
    }
    def parentDir = new MockFor(File)
    parentDir.demand.eachDir { Closure closure ->
      closure(subDir)
      closure(subDir)
    }
    def helper = new DirectoryNameHelper()

    when:
    def result
    parentDir.use {
      result = helper.getUpperCaseDirectoryNames(new File('parentDir'))
    }

    then:
    result == ['SUBDIR1', 'SUBDIR2']
  }

  static class DirectoryNameHelper {
    List<String> getUpperCaseDirectoryNames(File dir) {
      List<String> names = []
      dir.eachDir { File f ->
        names << f.name.toUpperCase()
      }
      names
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this... but there must be something I don't understand: mocking `getName()`, `exists()`, `isDirectory()` and `listFiles()` on my directory (`dir` in your `DirectoryNameHelper` class) doesn't iterate through any (mock) files... My understanding was that Syzmon was saying I have to get rid of `eachDir` and use `listFiles` in my app code instead.  I also get "InvalidSpecException: Mock object type cannot be inferred automatically" from your `Mock()` lines.  I have to put `Mock( File )` in both cases. Are we using different Groovy versions perhaps?  I'm using 2.6.

Comment: I like your idea of examining the Groovy source code though.  Please see addendum to my question...

Comment: @mikerodent You got my suggestion wrong. I didn't suggest getting rid of `eachDir` from your app code. I was suggesting not mocking `eachDir` in your test code and mocking `listFiles()` method that is a supplier of files inside the directory for `eachDir`. And you have to be aware that if you decide mocking a file you have to mock all its public methods to simulate specific scenarios like: file is a dir, file is a text file I don't have permissions to etc.

Comment: I use Groovy 2.4.7. When looking at the [groovy-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) Maven artifact, you see, that there is a 2.5 release candidate, 2.6 and 3.0 are still in alpha state. With them my tests do not even compile when I quickly tested it just now. For [spock-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core) there is a 1.1-groovy-2.4 version as the latest release. So I recommend you stick with Groovy 2.4 for the moment.

Comment: I forgot to mention: Not just Maven Central says that Groovy 2.6 is in alpha state, but also http://groovy-lang.org/download.html. So why don't you do yourself a favour and use a stable version instead of telling three guys here who want to help you that their code does not work?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about 2.4.  I haven't told "three guys" that "their code does not work", I merely pointed out politely to you that my attempt to run your code didn't work and wondered whether we were using different versions.

Comment: I did not say you were impolite. But you are trying to do advanced testing stuff and it never even occurred to you to mention that you are playing around with a bleeding-edge alpha version of Groovy until you had problems with running my code. Too many moving targets, man. I wonder why any experienced developer would do that, creating an environment for himself which makes it harder to debug instead of easier when trying something new. When there is a problem you never know if it's you or the environment itself.